# I cannot login to a netbook: “NO BOOTABLE DEVICE. HIT ANY KEY.”

Tags: windows-10, boot

I cannot login due to the following error:

```
NO BOOTABLE DEVICE. HIT ANY KEY.
```

but upon hitting any key it will pop-up another error:

```
NO BOOTABLE DEVICE. PLEASE RESTART SYSTEM.
```

I restart the system but still I cannot access my netbook. Here are the information of my netbook:

```
LENOVO IDEAPAD 100S 11IBY
BIOS VERSION: E2CN13WW
EC VERSION: E2EC12WW
LENOVO SN: 8S5B20K3893212YD62U07ZX
CPU: INTEL(R) ATOM(TM) CPU Z3735F @ 1.33GHz
STORAGE: Hynix HBG4e
SYSTEM MEMORY: 2048 MB
WINDOWS: 10 32-bit
```

I tried to used the NOVO MENU but still no luck. I cannot change the Secure Boot Mode in BIOS and the BOOT OPTION MENU list is empty. and it won't boot even by DVD/CD or USB.

Please help me to fix this one. the warranty is already expire.

Comment: It sounds like your MBR got hosed or maybe something else is wrong with your system drive.  What were you doing when the problem appeared?  What have you tried to boot from DVD/CD and USB?  Be sure to allow for those boot devices in BIOS, and you may have to hit F8 (or whatever your board uses) to bring up the boot menu.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: First You have remove the Hard Disk in your laptop than conncet onther system ones hard disk detect than format the HDD (slow format) ones Format complete than connect hard disk drive in your laptop and Start re-installation OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to re-seat the hard disk as, over time, the connectors can oxidise and get dirty causing a bad connection which results in the hard disk no longer being detected (and hence not being able to be booted from).

This does mean you will need to look up how to remove the hard disk from your netbook - some are easy and take only a few minutes but you'll possibly need a small Phillips screwdriver or some small torx/security screwdriver if the manufacturer has used these.

Make sure the netbook is out of warranty before dismantling or employ a professional.

If the hard disk is re-seated and it still doesn't work then the disk may have failed.